# Why does a second reference to a promise not resolve in Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm attempting to assign a reference to a Promise, prior to its resolution, to a variable.  I had expected that when the promise resolves in Promise.all, the reference to that same promise would be resolved too but instead it's still a promise object, not the resolved value

```js
function returnPromise(out) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(out);
    }, 1000);
  })
}

let test1;

let promiseStack = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let prom = returnPromise(i);
  promiseStack.push(prom);
  if (i === 1) {
    test1 = prom; // Set 1 of the references to a promise to a variable 
  }
}

Promise.all(promiseStack).then((results) => {
  console.log(results); // An array of 10 values (0 to 9)
  console.log(test1); // A promise object - expected this to be = 1
})
```

My question is, why does the test1 value not appear as resolved in the Promise.all block?

Comment: "*I had expected that (the reference to) that promise would be resolved too but instead it's still a promise object*" - no, promises don't "become" the value they resolve with. They are separate entities, they *contain* the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> test1 = prom; // Set 1 of the references to a promise to a variable
> ```

You assign a promise to `test1`.

You never assign another value to `test1`.

When you examine `test1` with:

> ```
> console.log(test1); // A promise object - expected this to be = 1
> ```

… it is still a promise.

---

You only see the resolved value of a promise when you do something that explicitly examines the resolved value of it (e.g. look at the argument passed to a function you pass to `then`).

The promise object itself is never transformed into the resolved value.

```
test1.then(value => console.log(value)); // This will be 1
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank-you.  For some reason, I had it in my head that the resolved value would take the place of the promise which is rather silly!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why does the test1 value not appear as resolved in the Promise.all block?

It does. It's a *resolved* promise at that point (and it shows as such in Chrome's devtools; you can't directly observe that state in code, though). Nothing in your code updates the `test1` variable after you assign it the promise instance, so naturally it still refers to the promise instance (a resolved one). Promises don't (and can't) go back and update all the variables that point to them to change them to the resolved value.